# How to make two cell arrays in same order according to one string column in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, compare

I have two cell arrays which are obtained from csv files (by textscan method). First column of arrays are type of string. Each string in one array is also included in the other array, but in different place (index). I want to make order of both array same?

Here is an example

`A=['abc' 3 5
    'def' 3 6
    'ghi' 1 1]`

`B=['ghi' 12 51
    'abc' 23 26
    'def' 12 34]`

I want to have B array same order as A array. For this example result of B (or Bnew) should be like this:

`Bnew=['abc' 23 26
       'def' 12 34
       'ghi' 12 51]`

How can I do this in Matlab by not using for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
A = {'abc' 3 5
    'def' 3 6
    'ghi' 1 1};
B = {'ghi' 12 51
    'abc' 23 26
    'def' 12 34}; %// example data. Cell arrays

[~, ind] = ismember(B(:,1), A(:,1));
[~, ind2] = sort(ind);
Bnew = B(ind2,:);
```

Result:

```
Bnew = 
    'abc'    [23]    [26]
    'def'    [12]    [34]
    'ghi'    [12]    [51]
```

Answer (score 0):

[sortrows](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) is the function you are looking for code example below:

e.g

```
Bnew = sortrows(B, 1);
```

1 is to sort by the first column

Comment: Yeah, your right but you could sort both to get a consistent order for both which is what the OP is looking for. Also A is sorted in the given example.